# <a href=""> including <iframe> does not work

Tags: html, iframe

I have this situation:

```html
<a href="http://www.google.ru" target="_blank">
      <iframe frameborder="0" style="background-color: transparent;" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" width="300px" height="200px;>
        <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
          <img height="131" width="300" src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-logo-alt2-300.png" alt="" />
        </body>
        </html>
      </iframe>
    </a>
```

`<A>` tag including `<iframe>`. The problem is that the link doesn't work: you can click it, but nothing's going on. How can I fix it?
Browser: FF38, Chrome42

Comment: Maybe it's because that's invalid HTML? `The element iframe must not appear as a descendant of the a element.` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html

Comment: you can not put an iframe in an inline-block element

Comment: Point is that I have to run a link, then user clicks iframe. It is condition of the task

Comment: @MaksimSlepov, i guess you should use JS, and move the iframe out of the `<a>`, and trigger the click with JS

Comment: [Links are interactive content, and may not include interactive content as descendants](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/single-page.html#the-a-element). `<iframe>` is interactive content as well. What you are asking to do is called "clickjacking".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking how to implement potentially malicious code.

Comment: @zzzzBov Why offtopic? It's real product problem I have to solve.

Answer (score 1):

As has been commented, this is invalid HTML.  You can accomplish the same thing by covering the iframe with a `div` or `display: block` anchor, or in this case simply by getting rid of the iframe and having an image alone instead.

If your html is:

```
<iframe id="if-id" src="something">
    <!--stuff-->
</iframe>
<a id="a-id" href="somewhere.com"></a>
```

Then your css might be:

```
#if-id {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1; /* for clarity */
}

#a-id {
    position: absolute;
    display: block; /* so anchor can take dimensions */
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iframe instantiates a new window inside current one. I don't think it's possible to set listener on the inner content so then it will be broadcasted to parent one!!

Answer (score -1):

You could add a listener to the iframe and open a link when the frame is clicked

I suggest:

```
$('#iframeid').click(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.ru'
});
```